# significance of this recursive function

Tags: javascript, math, recursion

Want to know the significance of the following function

```
var abc=(function(a, b){
    return a == 0 ? 0 : abc(a -1, b) + b;
});
(function(){
    var a = abc(10, 10);
    console.log(a);
})();
```

I know the output of the following function is 100 but what is it call in Mathematics?

Comment: Yeah, it is integer multiplication.

Comment: It is multiplication a×b

Comment: just simulate multiplication by plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a visual representation of how it is working,

```
abc(9, 10) + 10
abc(8, 10) + 10 + 10
abc(7, 10) + 10 + 10
abc(6, 10) + 10 + 10 + 10
abc(5, 10) + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10
abc(4, 10) + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10
abc(3, 10) + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10
abc(2, 10) + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10
abc(1, 10) + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10
abc(0, 10) + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10
0 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10
```

Its basically performing multiplication of two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

it is **multiplication**: by adding var b , a times.

```
var abc=(function(a, b){
    return a == 0 ? 0 : abc(a -1, b) + b;// here every time a is decreaded by 1 and abc() is called i.e. adding b, a time.
});
(function(){
    var a = abc(10, 10);
    console.log(a);
})();
```